# joomla: how to do submenus

Tags: joomla, menu, submenu

I would like a menu with sub-menus.

**1** - I would like to avoid accordions

**2** - major categories don't need to be click-able

**3** - it seems like that once I create an article and assign it somehow to the menu system, that the menu system should be able to automatically include the article title&link into the proper place within the menu.

[image: only the article links (in blue) need to be click-able]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the red menu items, go to "type" and choose "text separator". This will ensure that they are non clickable.

As for the blue menu items, create them like you would do for any other menu item, but select the "parent" according to whichever menu item you want them to appear under.

I think this is what you're looking for but if not, please explain in more detail as to what you require.

Regards

Comment: thanks Lodder ... that solved by issues **1** and **2** (although it has styled them in a grey-out color). It looks like I will not be able to get **3** solved. Instead apparently I must create an article and then after that manually create a menu item that points to that article.

Comment: @Lodder should the sub menu items be in the same parent menu? Can't it be a different menu by itself? I tried a different menu but it doesn't show the parent items

Comment: @itsols - the red ones are the parents and the blue ones are the children. Only make it a different menu if you will be putting it in a different area